# Joining and grouping two data tables

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I've got the following two data tables :

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:3,val1=c("a","a","b"),key="id")
#    id val1
# 1:  1    a
# 2:  2    a
# 3:  3    b


dt2 <- data.table(id=c(1:3,1:2),val2=10:14,key="id")
#    id val2
# 1:  1   10
# 2:  1   13
# 3:  2   11
# 4:  2   14
# 5:  3   12
```

Let's say that `dt1` is a list of people identified by their `id`, and `dt2` a list of observations on these same people, with the correspondent `id`.

Now, I'd like to compute the mean of `val2` for each group of `val1`. I've understood that I can do it the following way :

```
dt1[dt2][,mean(val2),by=val1]
#    val1 V1
# 1:    a 12
# 2:    b 12
```

But I've also read in the FAQ (section 1.14) that it's not efficient (at least for very large data tables).

So, is there a better, more efficient way to do it ?

**EDIT :** Another related question : I just saw that the following two lines will give the same result :

```
dt1[dt2][,mean(val2),by=val1]
dt2[dt1][,mean(val2),by=val1]
```

Are they equivalent or is there a difference between the two ?

Comment: I suspect the reshape package could help (though I don't have a detailed solution for you yet).  Transform both data sets to long form, join them together, and transform them back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, it's okay to do that. What the documentation explains, iiuc, is for example in this scenario (where you are not grouping/aggregating on ALL the columns):

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:3,val1=c("a","a","b"),key="id")
dt2 <- data.table(id=c(1:3,1:2),val2=10:14,key="id")

dt2[, val3 := rep(5:7, c(2,1,2))]
#    id val2 val3
# 1:  1   10    5
# 2:  1   13    5
# 3:  2   11    6
# 4:  2   14    7
# 5:  3   12    7
```

Now, suppose you want to get the mean of `val2` alone for every `val1`, then there's no point in joining all columns. In this case, you can do:

```
dt1[dt2, list(val1, val2)][, mean(val2), by=val1]
#    val1 V1
# 1:    a 12
# 2:    b 12
```

Instead of doing:

```
# gives same result but performs join on all columns
dt1[dt2][, mean(val2), by=val1]
```

---

For your second question, I guess it's essential to understand the difference `dt1[dt2]` and `dt2[dt1]`. For this, your data is not the best example. Suppose that,

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=c(1,4,5), val1=c("a","a","b"))
dt2 <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,6,7,8), val2=c(6,5,3,4,2,1))

setkey(dt1, "id")
setkey(dt2, "id")
```

`dt1[dt2]` takes, for every `id` in `dt2` and fetches the corresponding value of all other columns in `dt1` to perform the join:

```
dt1[dt2]
#    id val1 val2
# 1:  1    a    6
# 2:  2   NA    5
# 3:  3   NA    3
# 4:  6   NA    4
# 5:  7   NA    2
# 6:  8   NA    1
```

`dt2[dt1]` takes for every `id` in `dt1` the corresponding value from other columns of `dt2`  to perform the join:

```
dt2[dt1]
#    id val2 val1
# 1:  1    6    a
# 2:  4   NA    a
# 3:  5   NA    b
```

Note that, the values in `dt1[dt2]` contains *only* the id of `dt2`. Similarly `dt2[dt1]` contains only those in `dt1`. In your case, since the `id`s are exactly the same (ignorning the amount of times they occur), both the join would give you identical joins (except for the order of the columns), iiuc.

---

Just to make this part complete, if you want a "full" join, use `merge` with `all=TRUE`. The `merge.data.table` method is implemented.

```
merge(dt1, dt2, all = TRUE)

merge(dt1, dt2, all.x = TRUE) 
# is equivalent to
dt2[dt1]

merge(dt1, dt2, all.y = TRUE)
# is equivalent to
dt1[dt2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew you will be the first :) I just added a second related question in my question text, if you have some time to spend on it...

Comment: That's perfectly clear, I hope I could give you several upvotes... Thanks for taking the time to answer so clearly. Now I just have to understand the different values of `.N` in both cases. But that is another question :)

Comment: There was an error in the earlier explanation of answer to question 2, maybe you should read again. sorry about that.